# Software and Tools for one person owned business

Tags: windows, ubuntu

My Girlfriend helps a bit, but for the most part, it's myself working.

I do transportation modeling, anywhere from modeling traffic flows, traffic impact studies, transit studies, safety impact studies, to transportation policy.

The tools I can't live without are:

- Ubuntu

  - QGIS
  - PostgreSQL and PostGIS
  - Grass
  - SKype
  - Codeweaver that runs MsOffice 2007
  - **EDIT ADDED:** PyDev/Eclipse
  - **EDIT ADDED:** Gnome DO
- VirtualBox - Win Vista

  - Microsoft Office 2007
  - CAD and Transportation Software I use
  - Adobe Acrobat

I currently do most if not all of the business work through Excel and Word. I live in Canada and I was wondering what are some of the products you use for business purposes: inventory, invoicing, tendering, backup, email logs, data interoperability.

What are some of the proprietary or open-source tools that'll make my life easier? The more tools and suggestions you mention, the better as I'm willing to try a solution at least once.

**EDIT**
Concerning the comment some of the issues I have difficulties with include:

- Optimize my project organization: in a lot of my projects, the input data is similar, but the clients and project are different, so a good file/project manager
- My invoice system is basically an excel workbook per year, and each tab represents a new invoice. The same goes to bids and inventory.
- I use Gnome Do for logging in project hours, but a lot of times, I forget to turn it on.
- I use PGadmin III to manage my postgresql, It'll be nice if there were addons to that.
- A good organization system, that is dedicated to organizing projects

I hope that answers the comment

Comment: I think if you're looking for tools and software but you don't know what need or problem you're trying to solve, you're going about it backwards...

Comment: If your primary environment is ubuntu, why are you using Excel & Word rather than open office?  Very few people I work with are even aware that most of the 'excel' files they receive from me we actually generated by open office.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open to using Gnome, have you considered [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/features.phtml)?  I've used it for myself, but my needs are very basic, so YMMV.  It's laid out according to the typical simple gnome style, but I found it very useful for invoicing especially.  Reads QIF if you're exchanging with quickbooks or your bank.

You can use it like you'd use a checkbook:

[image: Checking account example]

But you can orgainize you data any way you like:

[image: GnuCash in Ubuntu]

Answer (score 1):

Quickbooks or any accounting package...